# Using a data / row value as a column header using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Given an object of type `Sale`:

```
class Sale
{
    DateTime Date {get; set;}
    string CurrencySymbol {get; set;}
    decimal Amount {get; set}
}
```

Used within a `List` that is returned from an API: `List<Sales>`:

```
{01/01/2021, "£", 25.00}
{01/01/2021, "£", 10.00}
{01/01/2021, "£", 5.00}
{01/02/2021, "£", 2.50}
{01/02/2021, "£", 2.50}
{01/03/2021, "$", 1.00}
```

I am looking to group the data and display it like so:

| Date | Number Of Sales | £ | $ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2021 | 3 | 40.00 | 0.00 |
| 01/02/2021 | 2 | 5.00 | 0.00 |
| 01/03/2021 | 1 | 0.00 | 1.00 |
| Totals | 6 Sales | 45.00 | 1.00 |

A date can contain sales for any number of currencies.

I am doing something along the lines of:

```
sales.GroupBy(s => s.Date).Select(s => new SalesSummary()
    {
        Date = s.Key.Value,
        AmountGbp = s.Where(x => x.CurrencySymbol == "£").Sum(x => x.Amount),
        AmountDollar = s.Where(x => x.CurrencySymbol == "$").Sum(x => x.Amount),
        NumberOfSales = s.Count()
     });
```

grouping the date, and number of sales using `LINQ`, ending up with a new `SalesSummary` object, wherein `SalesSummary` is defined as such:

```
class SalesSummary
{
    DateTime Date {get; set;}
    int NumberOfSales {get; set;}
    decimal AmountDollar {get; set}
    decimal AmountGbp {get; set;}
}
```

Ideally I'd like not to define the currencies as `AmountDollar` etc and instead determine the correct currency by somehow using the original `Sale` objects. That way, any new currencies will not be an issue.

Is there a simple way of doing this, or do I need to stick with the defined currency properties on `SalesSummary` containing the summed total for each currency?

Comment: Yes, you need extra properties for each symbol.

Comment: What LINQ are you using: LINQ to Objects / SQL / EF 6.x / EF Core 2.0 / 2.1 / 3.x / 5.x / 6.x? What database provider? Can you show the code for your query so far?

Comment: @NetMage - I have updated my post (exact code not at hand but you'll get the idea) MSSQL is the provider, .NET 4,8, EF 6.

Comment: What type do you imagine the resulting class would be for currencies defined on the fly from the database?

Comment: if I am understanding you correctly, I am likely going to create an Enum that defines the currencies, since each currency has as corresponding id within the db that can be mapped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I just kept this simple without trying anything clever. Simplified for example purposes:

```
public class RawSale // this comes from db
{
    public DateTime Date {get; set;}
    public Enums.Currency Currency { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}

public class Sales
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalGbp { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalDollar { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfSales  { get; set; }
}

public class SalesSummary
{
    public List<Sales> Sales { get; set; }
    public int ToatlNumberOfSales { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalDollar { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalGbp { get; set; }
}

var sales = _salesService.getSales().GroupBy(sr => sr.Date).Select(s => new Sales()
{
    Date = s.Key.Value.Date,
    NumberOfSales  = s.Count(),
    TotalDollar = s.Where(r => r.Currency == Enums.Currency.Dollar).Sum(r => r.Amount),
    TotalGbp = s.Where(r => r.Currency == Enums.Currency.Gbp).Sum(r => r.Amount)           
}).ToList();

var salesSummary = new SalesSummary()
{
    Sales = sales,
    ToatlNumberOfPoliciesSold = sales.Sum(x => x.NumerOfSales),
    TotalDollar = sales.Sum(x => x.TotalDollar),
    TotalGbp = sales.Sum(x => x.TotalGbp)
};
```

I am guessing there's a way to combine the new SalesSummary() and the GroupBy() however the above does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a conditional when looping through the display

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Number Of Sales</th>
            <th>£</th>
            <th>$</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var record in SalesResult)
        {
        <tr>
            <td>@record.Date</td>
            <td>@record.NumberOfSales</td>
            <td>
                @if(record.CurrencySymbol == "£")
                {
                    @record.Amount
                }
            </td>
            <td>
                @if (record.CurrencySymbol == "$")
                {
                    @record.Amount
                }
            </td>
        </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks. I was going to do this originally but the amount could consist of sales under multiple currencies.

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    public class Program
    {
        
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Sale> sales = new List<Sale>() {
                new Sale() {Date = DateTime.Parse("01/01/2021"), CurrencySymbol = "£", Amount = 25.00M},
                new Sale() {Date = DateTime.Parse("01/01/2021"), CurrencySymbol = "£", Amount = 10.00M},
                new Sale() {Date = DateTime.Parse("01/01/2021"), CurrencySymbol = "£", Amount = 5.00M},
                new Sale() {Date = DateTime.Parse("01/02/2021"), CurrencySymbol = "£", Amount = 2.50M},
                new Sale() {Date = DateTime.Parse("01/02/2021"), CurrencySymbol = "£", Amount = 2.50M},
                new Sale() {Date = DateTime.Parse("01/03/2021"), CurrencySymbol = "$", Amount = 1.00M}
            };

            var groups = sales.GroupBy(x => x.Date);

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Number Of Sales", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("£", typeof(decimal));
            dt.Columns.Add("$", typeof(decimal));

            foreach (var group in groups)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {
                    group.Key.ToString("mm/dd/yyyy"),
                    group.Count().ToString(),
                    group.Where(x => x.CurrencySymbol == "£").Sum(x => x.Amount),
                    group.Where(x => x.CurrencySymbol == "$").Sum(x => x.Amount)
                });

            }
            DataRow row = dt.Rows.Add();
            row["Date"] = "Totals";
            row["Number Of Sales"] = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => int.Parse(x.Field<string>("Number Of Sales")));
            row["£"] = dt.AsEnumerable().Sum(x => (decimal?)x.Field<object>("£"));
            row["$"] = dt.AsEnumerable().Sum(x => (decimal?)x.Field<decimal?>("$"));
 
        }
    }
    public class Sale
    {
        public DateTime Date {get; set;}
        public string CurrencySymbol {get; set;}
        public decimal Amount { get; set;  }
    }
 
 
}
```

Comment: thanks. A data table never crossed my mind. In the end I went with a new object, that contained a list the sales items and some properties to track the total for different currency types and overall number of sales.

Comment: Your original output class didn't make a lot of sense.  That is why I used the table.  Also if you need to write data back to the database the table makes it easier.  You can use Bulk Copy method.